# Moodle Profile page not found

Tags: php, moodle

So when any user clicks on "Profile" it goes to a "Page not found". Everyone can edit their profile on "Preferences" but if i click on "Profile" nothing.

The link goes to "mywebsite.com\moodle\user\profile.php?id=2" and on the logs it sais that the user with id 2 viewed their profile. The problem is it returns to the companies website saying "Page not found"

I'm still trying to understand profile.php because it exists.

Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: Try using Firebug or developer tools to capture the sequence of redirects and then add them to your question.

Comment: @Pete I may not  be doing the right thing but it can't locate profile.php?id=28.  The first one is a 404 looking for "profile.php?id=28" The other stuff is related to the company website

Comment: @Pete I have the profile.php file so what could be wrong?

Comment: So i found out that there are no "mdl_user" tables on the mysql database. What do i do now? Kind of lost.